# Don't you think that DataFrame creation from list of Series is rather strange?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Suppose we have to series:

```
s1 = pd.Series('a', index=[1,2,3], name="Column One")
s2 = pd.Series('b', index=[1,2,3], name="Column Two")
```

As we could see from documentation ([here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-dict-of-series-or-dicts)), the suggested way to create DataFrame from number of Serires objects is using common python dictionary construction, like that of:

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

In such situation I have reasonable question, what goals for do we need `name` attribute in Series, if it even couldn't be used in construction like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s1, s2)
```

with outcome dataframe:

```
     Column    Column
     one       two  
+---+---------+---------+  
| 1 |    a    |    b    |
| 2 |   ...   |   ...   |
|                       |
```

Comment: use `pd.DataFrame([s1,s2]).T` or `pd.concat([s1,s2], axis=1)` both works

Comment: If your combining named series like this, just use `concat`: `pd.concat([s1, s2], 1)`

Comment: You could call `df = pd.DataFrame({s1.name: s1, s2.name: s2})` to grab the names of each series.

Comment: Use the transport method

Comment: @JoePatten, but then I should write `.name` for each column, what could be quite painful if I suppose have ten or more columns.

Comment: @SaiKumar great! But I really think it's more natural if index of used series goes to index of dataframe by default (not by transposing after creation).

Comment: @Alex-droidAD It's fine either way. It's how you prefer your output to look like.

Comment: @Alex-driod AD Use a dictionary comprehension. See my answer.

Comment: @Alex-droidAD ... just use `{s.name:s for s in series_list}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use dictionary comprehension, using the series name as the key and series as the value, and then form a dataframe:

Input:

```
d = {s.name: s for s in [s1,s2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output:

```
  Column One Column Two
1          a          b
2          a          b
3          a          b
```

Answer (score 0):

Transpose your dataframe.

```
df=df.T
```

done

Answer (score 0):

An arguably cleaner way of creating a dataframe from a list of series is via `pd.concat` along `axis=1`, i.e. columns. This uses the `name` property for each series within your input list:

```
s1 = pd.Series('a', index=[1,2,3], name="Column One")
s2 = pd.Series('b', index=[1,2,3], name="Column Two")

df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)

print(df)

  Column One Column Two
1          a          b
2          a          b
3          a          b
```

Comment: + with list comprehension usage as was mentioned by the others

Comment: @Alex-droidAD, Actually nobody's suggested list comprehension. A couple have mentioned dictionary comprehensions. But this solution removes the need for `dict`.

Comment: :) yes, there wasn't exactly suggestion of using list comprehension. Your method don't need any comprehension usage. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex-droidAD, No problem. Do select an answer here that helped and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left) so other users know.